# Any fast boosting toolbox for MATLAB?

Tags: machine-learning, matlab

I have found some toolboxes for MATLAB but their execution is really slow thus I am searching for any faster implementation. If you have any suggestion about, please share with me. thanks...

Comment: Perhaps you can start by sharing what you found and what exactly you are looking for. Otherwise it will be hard to come up with suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There are many versions on the net, but I could not find any that would fit my needs, so I made my own, you can find at https://sites.google.com/site/carlosbecker/resources/gradient-boosting-boosted-trees.

It is multithreaded, provides MATLAB mex files and allows for both regression and classification. It is very fast, especially in comparison with MATLAB's built-in classifiers.

Hope that helps!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The Matlab Statistics Toolbox includes a regression ensemble (http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/regressionensembleclass.html) and a classification ensemble class (http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationensembleclass.html), both of which are reasonably fast.